# Salesforce JSON parsing error

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, json, javascript-remoting

I am having issues with JSON parsing. Here is my controller method:

```
    @RemoteAction
    global static String GetDetails(string sName)
    {
        //do soamething with sName later        
        List<String> sectorList = new List<String>();
        sectorList.add('Healthcare');
        sectorList.add('Healthcare');
        sectorList.add('Healthcare');
        return JSON.serialize(sectorList);
    }
```

& here is my JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getRemoteDeals(sectorName) {
        Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
            '{!$RemoteAction.MyController.GetDetails}',
            sectorName,
            function(result, event){
            if (event.status) {
                    //do something it is a success                      
                    alert(result);                      
                    var obj = JSON.parse(result);                        
                    alert(obj);
                } else if (event.type === 'exception') {
                    document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = 
                        event.message + "<br/>\n<pre>" + event.where + "</pre>";
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("responseErrors").innerHTML = event.message;
                }
            }, 
            {escape: true}
        );
    }
</script>
```

> Firebug error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1
>   column 2 of the JSON data

alert(result) throws this --> ["Healthcare","Healthcare","Healthcare"]

Also alert image attached:

[image: Please see image attached of the alert]

Comment: Try logging the `result` and add that to your question.

Comment: Please provide what values you get in result.

Comment: added result as an alert & image

Comment: what is the expected behaviour you are looking for ?

Comment: above code is not executing as expected. In firebug I get following error:
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have simpler method to do this.

Remote action method:

```
@RemoteAction
global static List<String> GetDetails(string sName)
{
    //do soamething with sName later        
    List<String> sectorList = new List<String>();
    sectorList.add('Healthcare');
    sectorList.add('Healthcare1');
    sectorList.add('Healthcare2');
    return sectorList;
}
```

There is no need to put JSON.parse because Salesforce return json only in following was so your

JS Method

```
// var obj = JSON.parse(result);    
alert(result[0]); //will print first value
alert(result[1]); //will print first value
alert(result[2]); //will print first value
```

Comment: Hi Himanshu, your above answer works if I have a list of string. If I use the above code and replace it with List<MyCustomObject__c> then my alerts are [object Object] irrespective of the object type. Any insights on that?

Comment: that is correct.

Comment: is there a way to retrieve object value?

Comment: it is simple json object parsing. you can use . notation to access the value.